# Best way to save objects with nested objects to a file?

Tags: c#, json, file, object, save

I'm working on this software where you can create a party to an RPG game and save it to a file. There's multiple `Member` objects which have nested classes like `Bag` and the `Bag` contains `Item` objects in an Item array. I tried to save the Heroes to a file by Serializing them with JSON but the problem is, **JSON doesn't save the type of the objects and the nested objects won't be there if I use something like `dataFromFile.ToObject<Member>`.**

What would be the best way to save Objects with nested objects to a file so it's easy to load them back and all the nested objects would be there too?

```
public class Member
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Race { get; set; }
    public int CarryingWeight { get; set; }
    public int MaxCarryWeight { get; set; }
    public int MaxMana { get; set; }
    public int MeleeAttack { get; set; }
    public int RangeAttack { get; set; }
    public int Defense { get; set; }
    public int MaxHealth { get; set; }

    IBag bag = new LargeBag();
}

public class LargeBag : IBag
{
    public int Weight { get; set; } = 7;
    IItem[] items = new IItem[12];
}

// I put all kinds of dynamic objects to a Dictionary and Serialized the whole 
// Dictionary with JSON, then saved it to a file.

Dictionary<string, dynamic> savedObjects = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();

        savedObjects.Add("hero1", Globals.member1);
        savedObjects.Add("hero2", Globals.member2);
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { ContractResolver = new 
MyContractResolver() };
        var saveData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(savedObjects, settings);

// When DeSerializing the Dictionary, i'm able to create the Heroes back with 
// .ToObject method, but the Bag's stuff aren't there
Dictionary<string, dynamic> loadedObjects = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();

        loadedObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, 
dynamic>>(loadData);

        Member loadedMember1 = loadedObjects["member1"].ToObject<Member>();
        Member loadedMember2 = loadedObjects["member2"].ToObject<Member>();

// JSON settings used
public class MyContractResolver : 
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver
    {
        protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, 
MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
        {
            var props = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | 
BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                            .Select(p => base.CreateProperty(p, 
memberSerialization))
                        .Union(type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | 
BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                                   .Select(f => base.CreateProperty(f, 
memberSerialization)))
                        .Where(p => !p.PropertyName.Contains("k__BackingField"))
                        .ToList();
            props.ForEach(p => { p.Writable = true; p.Readable = true; });
            return props;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, what isn't working and expected output so we can further help you. We need to be able to see what you are working with to help you figure out your issue, otherwise answer's for this are going to be opinionated and may or may not address your concern's.

Comment: What JSON serializer did you use? What went wrong? A serializer serializes/deserializes an object from/to a class model type you provide. Make `bag` a public Property.

Comment: hint: json.net + TypeNameHandling

Comment: If the Bag isn't public property, isn't it loaded even though it's nested object in a Member object?

Comment: It seems like the TypeNameHandling is the way to go here. Thank you Selvin :)

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the TypeNameHandling is the way to go here. Thank you Selvin :)

newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm